# Specman profiling external code

Tags: specman

I run profile on my specman run and get that 90% is on External Code.
My run environemnt includes SystemVerilog code also.
How can I identify what is this "External Code" and who is calling it?

Answer (score 0):

"External Code" usually accounts for non specman and non simulator code,
such as c/c++ code , non-Cadence simulator, etc...
in particular, if you are using the C interface (C-specman interface), and you define your
c routines as foreign dynamic, and you have the simulation configuration "-ignore_dyn_c_routine_signals" set to TRUE (which is the default value), then 
all foreign dynamic c routines will be considered as external code rather then spacman code.

In order to view the specman simulation configuration, issue this command in the specman prompt:

specman >  show config simulation

if you'd like some help analyzing the profiler reports, you can always contact Cadence support [here](http://support.cadence.com) and send the relevant reports.

Answer (score 0):

"External Code" might also include non-Cadence simulator, or even IUS too, if profiler is enabled for Specman only. If you click on "External Code" in "Code Blocks" table, you may see some "callers" - ports, dynamic C routines, etc - entities in e code that caused Specman to communicate with external code. In case that most of those 90% are spent in simulator between Specman ticks, or in C/C++ code called from simulator, you probably will not see any significant %s in "callers". But in this case most of your CPU time is spent on code not really related to Specman, and the profiler can't help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your System Verilog simulator is likely the master for your simulation, so if you want to analyze the "External Code", look in the documentation for your simulator about how to enable system verilog profiling.

If the System Verilog simulator says that it isn't consuming much simulation time, then fire up a C/C++ profiler like [Google Profiler](http://code.google.com/p/gperftools/) and it will tell you which exact C/C++ functions are being executed.  FYI, you may want to run the post-processing tool on your `/proc/<pid>/exe` while the process is still running in order to see all the symbols if things are getting `dlopen'd` in your simulation environment.